# How to test lambda?

Tags: java, testing, lambda

I have the following class with two methods:

```
public class AgentListView extends StandardListView<Agent> {

    private transient UiComponents uiComponents;

    private transient AgentService agentService;

    private transient Notifications notifications;

    private transient Messages messages;

    public AgentListView(UiComponents uiComponents,
            AgentService agentService,
            Notifications notifications,
            Messages messages) {
        this.uiComponents = uiComponents;
        this.agentService = agentService;
        this.notifications = notifications;
        this.messages = messages;
    }

    @ViewComponent
    private DataGrid<Agent> agentsDataGrid;

    @Subscribe
    public void onInit(final InitEvent event) {
        addDropdownButtonInColumn();
    }

    public void addDropdownButtonInColumn() {
        Grid.Column<Agent> column = agentsDataGrid.getColumnByKey("additionally");
        DropdownButton dropdownButton = uiComponents.create(DropdownButton.class);
        dropdownButton.setIcon(VaadinIcon.ELLIPSIS_DOTS_V.create());
        dropdownButton.addItem("edit", agentsDataGrid.getAction("edit"));
        dropdownButton.addItem("checkStatusAgent", agentsDataGrid.getAction("checkStatusAgent"));
        dropdownButton.addItem("read", agentsDataGrid.getAction("read"));
        ComponentRenderer<DropdownButton, Agent> componentRenderer = new ComponentRenderer<>(agent ->
        dropdownButton);
        column.setRenderer(componentRenderer);
    }
}
```

In the AgentListView test class I use integration testing to test the onInit() method as follows:

```
@Test
void testOnInit() {

    viewNavigators.view(AgentListView.class).navigate();

    AgentListView agentListView = UiTestUtils.getCurrentView();

    agentListView.onInit(mock(View.InitEvent.class));
}
```

Ultimately Jacoco highlights the dropdownButton in red in the row

```
ComponentRenderer<DropdownButton, Agent> componentRenderer = 
       new ComponentRenderer<>(agent -> dropdownButton);
```

As I understand it, this means that the code in the lambda was not called, but I can’t figure out how to call it so that the tests pass completely.

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: That lambda will be called when the component is rendered, not when it's created, so you would need another test.

Comment: @tgdavies that is, I also need to test the addDropdownButtonInColumn() method?

Comment: No, you need to call whatever method will use the renderer (I'm not sure what framework you're using)